# How to Delete the Subtotals from Google Sheet's Pivot Table

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

How to Delete the Grand Total and Subtotals from Google Sheet's Pivot Table?

Comment: Please mark the answer if it is the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 15):

The pivot table editor on the right side has a checkbox called `Show Totals`.